# Distance contraction and acceleration

Tags: special-relativity, acceleration

I'm trying to understand length contraction. I've created a diagram with three examples. I'm wondering if my diagram is correct. According to this diagram, when you accelerate towards an object, the distance between yourself and the object will get shorter. If you accelerate away from an object, the distance gets longer. Is my diagram correct?

[image: diagram]

Comment: If you do not include the logic that led you to these diagrams, nobody can help you pinpoint your error.

Answer (score 1):

Your diagrams are incorrect.

The distance between two points is frame dependent. In the frame in which the two points are stationary, the distance is known as the 'proper' distance between the points. In other frames moving in the direction of the line between the two points, the distance will decrease with speed according to the length contraction formula of special relativity.

The effect is the same whether you accelerate towards A or away from A.

The effect arises from the relativity of simultaneity. I will try to explain it with an analogy. You can determine the length of a moving object, such as a train, by noting the positions of its two ends at the same instant and measuring the distance between those two points. As a consequence of the relativity of simultaneity, when you think you are noting the positions of the front and rear of the train at exactly the same time, in the frame of the train you are actually noting the position of the front of the train before you note the position of the rear; as a result, the train will seem shorter because the rear will have moved forward in the time gap between the two measurements.